# What means this.state.backClick== 1 ? BackHandler.exitApp() : this._spring() in react native?

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I'm new in react native and I was searching how to do "press twice to exit app" ,actually I found how but I didn't understand the code and I don't like to copy without understanding things .

```
      state = {backClickCount: 0};

      constructor(props) {super(props);this.springValue = new Animated.Value(100);}

      componentWillMount() {BackHandler.addEventListener('hardwareBackPress', this.handleBackButton.bind(this));}

      componentWillUnmount() {BackHandler.removeEventListener('hardwareBackPress', this.handleBackButton.bind(this));}

      _spring() {
          this.setState({backClickCount: 1}, () => {
              Animated.sequence([
                  Animated.spring(
                      this.springValue,
                      {
                          toValue: -.15 * height,
                          friction: 5,
                          duration: 300,
                          useNativeDriver: true,
                      }
                  ),
                  Animated.timing(
                      this.springValue,
                      {   toValue: 100,
                          duration: 300,
                          useNativeDriver: true,}),
              ]).start(() => {
                  this.setState({backClickCount: 0});
              });
          });
      }


      handleBackButton = () => {
          this.state.backClickCount == 1 ? BackHandler.exitApp(): this._spring();
          return true;
      }
```

I want understand this instruction :  `this.state.backClickCount == 1 ? BackHandler.exitApp() this._spring();`

and If you can tell where to add     `shortToast('Press again to quit the application!');`

Answer (score 0):

If you’re asking about the question mark/colon syntax: It’s a [ternary expression](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator).

It’s the equivalent of:

```js
if (this.state.backClickCount == 1) {
  BackHandler.exitApp();
}
else {
  this._spring();
}
```